# Request data from raspberry pi to arduino over serial bluetooth

Tags: python-2.7, arduino, serial-port, raspberry-pi2

Im trying to send data from an arduino with integrated ble (bluno nano from DFRobot) to a raspberry pi 2 which has an hm10 ble module connected to its serial0 gpio14 and 15 pins.

Im currently using this sketch:

```
float flow = 500.06;
void setup() {
  Serial.begin( 9600 );}
void loop() {
    if (Serial.available()>0) {
        if (Serial.read() == 'R') {
             Serial.print(flow)
             Serial.write("\n");
        }
    }
}
```

and Im using this python to read it:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
import serial
from time import sleep
ser = serial.Serial(port='/dev/serial0',parity=serial.PARITY_NONE,
        stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE,bytesize=serial.EIGHTBITS,timeout=1)
# Wait to read from Arduino
while 1:
        try:
                time.sleep(10)
                ser.write("R")
                myData = ser.readline()
                print myData
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
                exit()
```

This should make the raspberry send R to the arduino after 10 seconds of running the script.  But I get blank lines in the raspberry terminal every ten seconds.  I guess that is the print myData line, which is coming in blank.

I just tried connecting the bluno nano and the raspberry pi 2 over usb serial and ran this code and the rpi received 82, which is the ascii equivalent of R. Ive modified the code and added an image to display these findings. I still dont understand why I dont get the response when its over bluetooth serial?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The Arduino needs to wait for the signal from the Raspberry Pi.
For example by reading a character `'R'`.

```cpp
float flow = 500.06;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin( 9600 );
}
void loop() {
    if (Serial.available()>0) {
        if (Serial.read() == 'R') {
             Serial.print(flow);
             Serial.write("\n");
        }
    }
}
```

The Raspberry Pi needs to send the character `'R'`, before reading the data from the Arduino.

```py
import serial
import time
ser = serial.Serial(port='/dev/serial0',parity=serial.PARITY_NONE,
        stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE,bytesize=serial.EIGHTBITS,timeout=1)
# Wait to read from Arduino
while 1:
    try:
        time.sleep(10)
        ser.write("R")
        myData = ser.readline()
        print myData
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        ser.close()
        exit()
```

Comment: I modified the OP to include your solution but something is still missing.  I dont think any data is coming through from the Arduino.

Comment: I tested your code and after fixing the obvious compiler errors, the code worked fine.

Comment: the one i now have in the OP? Are you using bluetooth over serial?

Comment: I am using just serial on Windows. If your Bluetooth is paired and connected the code should work. Are you only able to send the data from an Arduino, but can't receive it?

Comment: No. If I type into the Arduino IDE Serial Monitor, those values show up on the raspberry terminal. I can also make the data be sent from the arduino sketch to the raspberry terminal. Its what I send from the raspberry that doesnt show up or seem to be recognized on the Arduino side.

Comment: I just tried connecting the bluno nano and the raspberry pi 2 over usb serial and ran this code and the rpi received 82, which is the ascii equivalent of R.  Ive modified the code and added an image to display these findings.  I still dont understand why I dont get the response when its over bluetooth serial?

Comment: Don't edit my answer and add your own questions to it. Also you shouldn't change your question to change your problem. You already have 3k rep and should already know how this Q&A site works.

Comment: And relating to your problem. `Serial.read()` (and other reading functions) consume characters from the serial buffer. If you read it once to print it out, the next read for comparison will return -1, since there is nothing in the serial buffer anymore.

Comment: I am not quite sure how Bluetooth on a Bluno Nano works, but it looks like it's just connected to `Serial`. If you have anything else connected to serial it might interfere with the communication. And if a simple serial echo sketch doesn't work, there might be a hardware problem, which are off-topic on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't know I had edited your answer, I didn't even know I could edit someone else's answer.  If I did it was probably cause I was trying to edit my OP to reflect new findings. Ok so it's specifically a Bluetooth issue then?

Comment: Could it have something to do with the AT command configuration?